# Django: IntegrityError at /accounts/accounts/myprofile UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_userprofile.user_id

Tags: django

When I am trying to update an existing userprofile i get this error,

IntegrityError at /accounts/accounts/myprofile
UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_userprofile.user_id

I have searched for solutions, but it does not work for me.

model:

class UserProfile(models.Model):

```
is_deligate = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_candidate = models.BooleanField(default=False)

user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)

name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
stud_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
course_year_and_section = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Form:

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['name','stud_id','course_year_and_section']
```

view:

def UserProf(request):

```
user = request.user
ls2 = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
form = UserProfileForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = request.user
        profile.save()
context = {'form':form,'ls2':ls2}
return render(request,"accounts/myprofile.html", context)
```

def UpdateUserProf(request):

```
form = UserProfileForm()
try:
    prof = request.user
except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
    prof = UserProfile(user=request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST,instance=prof)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        
        return redirect("myprofile.html")
else:
     form = UserProfileForm(instance=prof)
context = {'form':form}
return render(request,"accounts/myprofile.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

CustomUser can only have one UserProfile,that's what OneToOneField means, maybe you are trying to set a UserProfile for a CustomUser with an existing one. Check whether this helps.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    is_deligate = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_candidate = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stud_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    course_year_and_section = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def UserProf(request):
    user = request.user
    ls2 = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
    form = UserProfileForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save()
    context = {'form':form,'ls2':ls2}
    return render(request,"accounts/myprofile.html", context)
```

Comment: it worked after I removed primary_key from stud_id and put it in user.